# How to display multiple lines in a label?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I need to code a program that will calculate quarterly payments using the rate and principal. I need to be able to calculate what that would be for 2 - 5 years. This is the code that I have, I am having trouble displaying multiple lines in the label of the program. I'm not even sure if my equation works correctly.

Dim decnum As Integer 
For decnum = 2 To 5 
lblPayments.Text = Val(txtPrincipal.Text) + (decnum * Val(txtPrincipal.Text) * Val(txtRate.Text))

Here is the prompt for reference:
The interface provides text boxes for the user to enter the principal and the annual interest rate (as a decimal number). Both text boxes should accept only numbers, the period, and the Backspace key. The Calculate Quarterly Payments button should calculate the quarterly payments for terms of 2, 3, 4, and 5 years. If the interest rate is entered as an integer (which means it’s greater than or equal to 1), convert the integer to its decimal equivalent by dividing it by 100. Display the terms and quarterly payments in the lblPayments control. Code the appropriate event procedures. Use the For…Next statement to calculate the quarterly payments. Save the solution and then start and test the application. Close the Code Editor window and then close the solution.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb3sbadh(v=vs.110).aspx